# Method Call with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have got a exercise for Ruby, and don't know how to make it! I'm still a newb, and learning my way in programming world, but I can't resolve this exercise. If you could also explain to me how you made it, that'd be great!

Here it is :

Write a method double on object account which returns the double of its input parameter num.

```
def account.double(num)
    #your code here
end

# call double here
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Where do you misunderstand? Do you know what is a method? Parameter? Do you know how values are returned? Or perhaps having troubles writing arithmetics?

Comment: Please don't use this site to have other people doing your homework.

Answer (score 3):

```
def account.double(num)
    num*2    
end

account.double(54)
```

In ruby, methods `return` value of the last statement if `return` value is not specified explicitly. Here `num*2` is returned by the method.

We are calling `account.double` at the end of the program using 54 as the number. You can use any other number you like.

Just remember that the account object should be created, before this double method can be defined/called. I am leaving that to you as an exercise.